# Python Pandas - Initialising and Populating a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry, a real numpty question here:

Why does the following code not produce a dataframe with values in?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['First'] = 68
df['Second'] = 157
```

How should I modify the code? I'm looking for the column names to be `First` and `Second` and the corresponding values to be `68` and `157`.

This is only a simple example to illustrate the difficulty I'm having. In the actual code I go through a series of code to find the relevant values, so the dataframe cannot be initialised and completed in a single step using dictionaries.

Each column in the dataframe will only have one value. The dataframe will then be returned from the function, with the values appended to the "master" dataframe. If dataframes aren't the data structure I should be using to achieve this then please advise.

Thanks

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'First':[68],'Second':[157]})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = pd.DataFrame()` produces an empty dataframe...  But it's more empty than other empty dataframes.  It has no index and no columns.

`df['First'] = 68` assigns the value of 68 to a column named `'First'` for every index value.  You'll note that the columns `['First', 'Second']` now exist.  There were simply no index values for which to make the assignments of `68` and `157`

This may be more obvious if I add an index to your `df` construction.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1, 2, 3])
df['First'] = 68
df['Second'] = 157

print(df)

   First  Second
1     68     157
2     68     157
3     68     157
```

Comment: Using this information I initialized my dataframe using `df = pd.DataFrame()` and then set the parameters using `df['first'] = [68]` and `df['second'] = [157]`. The key is the brackets around the values.